# How to restrict access to some Kubernetes namespace allowing access only by some pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: foo
  selector:
    app: foo
```

This service point to the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: foo
          image: gcr.io/foo:1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

I also have another deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bar
  labels:
    app: bar
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bar
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bar
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bar
          image: gcr.io/bar:1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

`foo` is deployed to Kubernetes namespace called `kube-protected`, `bar` is deployed to default Kubernetes namespace.

`foo` contains import data and should be well secured.

Kubernetes default namespace may also contain another deployments: `qux`, `baz`, etc.

I want to restrict access to service `foo` so only `bar` can access it. Or another way is to restrict access to `kube-protected` namespace so only `bar` can get into it.

**SOLUTION**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: namespace-which-you-want-to-protect-network-policy
  namespace: namespace-which-you-want-to-protect
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: namespace-which-is-only-allowed-to-access-protected-namespace
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: application-which-is-only-allowed-to-access-protected-namespace
  podSelector: {}
```

Comment: When you are referring to a resource from another namespace, you will need to mention the namespace, or else the resource will not be visible. So not sure if that help, but also do take a look at this [link](https://jeremievallee.com/2018/05/28/kubernetes-rbac-namespace-user.html).

Comment: @cookiedough Thank you for reply. I think RBAC is more to control access in the team but my question is about communication of pods. Check my solution in the bottom of my question.

Comment: @yivo Hey, i tried your solution, but it didn't work for me. do we need to create any additional helm file to restrict ingress access for namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this situation you can use Network policy to restrict access to **foo**

```
kind: NetworkPolicy

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

metadata:

  name: access-nginx

spec:

  podSelector:

    matchLabels:

      app: foo

  ingress:

  - from:

    - podSelector:

        matchLabels:

          app: bar
```

Comment: Didn't know this feature exists! Thank you so much! I will play with this and reply.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have posted a solution in the bottom of my question.